# How to write multiple arrays into one variable?

Tags: yii2

I need to write multiple arrays into one variable, f.e:

```
$test= Yii::$app->request->get('Test', []);
$test1 = Yii::$app->request->get('Test1', []);
$test2 = Yii::$app->request->get('Test2', []);
```

If I have these 3 statements, I want to join in together by using just only 1 variable. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to be more specific - give us some example of your desired output.

Comment: I don't know how to specify it more. I just simply want to write 1 variable instead of writing $test, $test1 and $test2, because it's repetetive.

Comment: But you said you want to join them. Join them how?

Comment: Em, maybe join is not correct word for it. F.e if I have $test1, $test2, and $test3 sentences, I need to write all 3 into 1 variable to not be repetetive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$test = Yii::$app->request->get();
```

You will get `array` with all your data.

Or if you want to specify indexes:

```
$test[] = Yii::$app->request->get('Test', []);
$test[] = Yii::$app->request->get('Test1', []);
$test[] = Yii::$app->request->get('Test2', []);
```

Comment: But some of my data are from different tables. F.e test is from the table 'table1', 'test2' => table2, 'test3' => 'table3'. Do I will get the array with all my data with that one `$test = Yii::$app->request->get();`?

Comment: Yes, it will get all Your GET data